# Populating DF with second DF

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I saw several  questions on this but none of the tricks I found worked.

I'm trying to populate all the NaN values of data frame based on values of a second data frame. The first df is huge and the second df will be acting as a key of sorts.

```
     DF1

    Part    System_Type   Replacement_Cost   Service_Life(Years)    Location

    nut       A/C             .09                 1                   TX
    Bolt      Generator        NAN                NAN                 MT
    screw     roof             .08                NAN                 UT
    screw     A/C              NAN                 3                  OH
    screw     roof             .08                NAN                 TX

    DF2
    Part    System_Type   Replacement_Cost   Service_Life(Years)  

    Bolt      Generator        .06                 2                
    screw     roof             .08                 3                
    screw     A/C              .08                 3
```

With an output like this

```
    Part    System_Type   Replacement_Cost   Service_Life(Years)    Location

    nut       A/C             .09                 1                   TX
    Bolt      Generator       .06                 2                   MT
    screw     roof            .08                 3                   UT
    screw     A/C             .08                 3                   OH
    screw     roof            .08                 3                   TX
```

I tried using df1.combine_first(df2) but I need it to fill all NANs with 'Part' and 'System_Type' both serving as keys to match up the data correctly. It seemed like it wasn't populating all of the missing values, just a few of them. My data set is millions of rows so I need it to fill the NANs each time that particular set of values comes up (i.e. each time it sees screw, and roof, it should populate  the replacement cost as '.08' and Service Life as '3')

Answer (score 2):

Assuming those `NAN` are `np.nan`

```
df1.fillna(df1[['Part', 'System_Type']].merge(df2, 'left'))

    Part System_Type  Replacement_Cost  Service_Life(Years) Location
0    nut         A/C              0.09                  1.0       TX
1   Bolt   Generator              0.06                  2.0       MT
2  screw        roof              0.08                  3.0       UT
3  screw         A/C              0.08                  3.0       OH
4  screw        roof              0.08                  3.0       TX
```

Otherwise, you can replace `NAN` with `np.nan`

```
df1.replace('NAN', np.nan).fillna(df1[['Part', 'System_Type']].merge(df2, 'left'))

    Part System_Type Replacement_Cost Service_Life(Years) Location
0    nut         A/C              .09                   1       TX
1   Bolt   Generator             0.06                   2       MT
2  screw        roof              .08                   3       UT
3  screw         A/C             0.08                   3       OH
4  screw        roof              .08                   3       TX
```

Comment: I keep getting an invalid index error but the column names are the same. There is also nothing in the index error it just says InvalidIndexError: